# Adding values (rows) from table to the other only for matching variables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on rail data for different years (2009 to 2014) but just recently received data for two more years (2015 and 2016) separately. So my current tables are as follows:

---

### Table1

```
YEAR....REV1....REV2....REV3....REV4....ORG....DEST  
2009.....12......14.....15......16......ABC.....ABD  
2010.....12......14.....15......16......ABC.....ABD  
2011.....12......14.....15......16......ABC.....ABD  
2012.....12......14.....15......16......ABC.....ABD  
2013.....12......14.....15......16......ABC.....ABD  
2014.....12......14.....15......16......ABC.....ABD  
2009.....12......14.....15......16......XYZ.....XCV  
2010.....12......14.....15......16......XYZ.....XCV  
2011.....12......14.....15......16......XYZ.....XCV  
2012.....12......14.....15......16......XYZ.....XCV  
2013.....12......14.....15......16......XYZ.....XCV  
2014.....12......14.....15......16......XYZ.....XCV
```

Note that the values 12,14,15,16 are just random number I wrote now, the value are different and differ from one year to the other. And the list go on giving rows for all the years for each different pair of ORG and DEST.

## Table2 (2015)

```
YEAR....REV1....REV2....REV3....REV4....ORG....DEST  
2015.....12......14.....15......16......ABC.....ABD  
2015.....12......14.....15......16......XYZ.....XCV  
2015.....12......14.....15......16......VRF.....AVC  
2015.....12......14.....15......16......DRE.....ACS  
2015.....12......14.....15......16......FRE.....AWD
```

## Table3 (2016)

```
YEAR....REV1....REV2....REV3....REV4....ORG....DEST  
2016.....12......14.....15......16......ABC.....ABD  
2016.....12......14.....15......16......XYZ.....XCV  
2016.....12......14.....15......16......VRF.....AVC  
2016.....12......14.....15......16......DRE.....ACS  
2016.....12......14.....15......16......FRE.....AWD
```

What i'd like to have is a table with all the years but adding only those that exists on the ORG AND DEST basis, as the new table (2015 and 2016) has data for a lot of other pairs of ORG and DEST that i'm not interested in but rather only those I have in my first table as below:

### Table1

```
YEAR....REV1....REV2....REV3....REV4....ORG....DEST  
2009.....12......14.....15......16......ABC.....ABD  
2010.....12......14.....15......16......ABC.....ABD  
2011.....12......14.....15......16......ABC.....ABD  
2012.....12......14.....15......16......ABC.....ABD  
2013.....12......14.....15......16......ABC.....ABD  
2014.....12......14.....15......16......ABC.....ABD
2015 ....12......14.....15......16......ABC.....ABD
2016.....12......14.....15......16......ABC.....ABD
2009.....12......14.....15......16......XYZ.....XCV  
2010.....12......14.....15......16......XYZ.....XCV  
2011.....12......14.....15......16......XYZ.....XCV  
2012.....12......14.....15......16......XYZ.....XCV  
2013.....12......14.....15......16......XYZ.....XCV  
2014.....12......14.....15......16......XYZ.....XCV  
2015.....12......14.....15......16......XYZ.....XCV
2016.....12......14.....15......16......XYZ.....XCV
```

I'm relatively new to SQL, so been reading about inner join but it seems to add columns rather than the rows I want. Any ideas on how I might do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you want `union all`.

Comment: yes in fact it is what I was looking for, thank mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 for your efforts. `Join` works on matching 2 different columns. What you want is `union` of different tables based on ORG and DEST conditions in `where`

```
 SELECT * FROM Table1 
 UNION SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE `ORG` LIKE 'XYZ' AND `DEST` LIKE 'XCV' 
 UNION SELECT * FROM Table3 WHERE `ORG` LIKE 'XYZ' AND `DEST` LIKE 'XCV'
```

in case you want repetitive data as well, use `UNION ALL` instead of union.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know about union before, it worked fine, thank you very much

Comment: @Mahmoud : Kindly mark it as answer if it helped, for other people if they stumble upon :)

Answer (score 0):

UNION Would make it, try something like below code

```
     SELECT * FROM Table1
     UNION
     SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE `ORG` LIKE 'XYZ' AND `DEST` LIKE 'XCV'
     UNION
     SELECT * FROM Table3 WHERE `ORG` LIKE 'XYZ' AND `DEST` LIKE 'XCV'
```

Comment: this is worked perfectly I didn't know about union, thanks a lot